# How to order my row's Dataset per Weekdays

Tags: python

I have the following Dataset:

```
Week   Day        Hours
Week 1 Monday     18769
Week 2 Wednesday  7231
```

Then, in order to map it in a Heatmap, I did:

`data = df.pivot(index="Day", columns="Week", values="Hours")`

The problem appears here since the row's dataset does not order the weekdays as it should, it goes like

- Sunday, Thursday, Monday, Tuesday, etc...

So I tried this:
`data["Day"] = pd.Categorical(data["Day"], categories=["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"], ordered=True)`

And I get the following error:

`KeyError: 'Day'`

Is there any other way to do this, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pivot on day like that, your dataset should become something like:

```
Week      1   2   3 ...
Day
"Sunday"  a   b   c
"Monday"  d   e   f
"Tuesday" g   h   i 
.
.
.
```

Where `a-i` are the hours. As you can see, day is no longer a column, but instead the index. This is why you are getting a key error. Print your dataframe after the pivot and you should see that. If you want to order the rows, you may just be best off manually ordering them as I don't know of a categorical way to sort indexes in pandas. You can also try pivoting differently.

Answer (score 0):

After you did `pivot`, you have no `Day` column. Now it's `data.index` with name `Day`

If i understand what you want, here is my code:

```
# prepare source data

dd = {'Week': {0: 'Week-1', 1: 'Week-2', 2: 'Week-3'},
 'Day': {0: 'Monday', 1: 'Sunday', 2: 'Wednesday'},
 'Hours': {0: 18769, 1: 1000, 2: 7231}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(diic)
df

Out[1]:
    Week    Day        Hours
0   Week-1  Monday      18769
1   Week-2  Sunday      1000
2   Week-3  Wednesday   7231

data = df.pivot(index="Day", columns="Week", values="Hours")
data

Out[2]:
    Week    Week-1  Week-2  Week-3
Day         
Monday      18769.0 NaN        NaN
Sunday      NaN     1000.0     NaN
Wednesday   NaN     NaN      7231.0

struc = {x[0]:x[1] for x in zip(["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"], range(7))}
struc

Out[3]:   # structure for prepare columns for sort
{'Monday': 0,
 'Tuesday': 1,
 'Wednesday': 2,
 'Thursday': 3,
 'Friday': 4,
 'Saturday': 5,
 'Sunday': 6}


data['day_n'] = data.index.map(struc)
data

Out[4]:

Week        Week-1  Week-2  Week-3  day_n
Day             
 Monday     18769.0   NaN      NaN    0
Sunday      NaN     1000.0     NaN    6
Wednesday   NaN       NaN    7231.0   2


data.sort_values(by = ['day_n']).  # sort by last column

Out[5]:
Week        Week-1  Week-2  Week-3  day_n
Day             
Monday      18769.0   NaN      NaN    0
Wednesday   NaN       NaN   7231.0    2
Sunday      NaN     1000.0    NaN     6
```